# Salary seems very low after joining, how to quit gracefully?

Tags: job-search, career-development, new-job, job-change, quitting

I recently joined a company which is located in Cambridge(UK) and this is the first time I am visiting this place. The office is a research organisation and its location is in a very remote area, the only transport is free shuttle service and that too is on specific times hence once you miss that then you are going to be hit hard by the high taxi fare. The cost of renting is expensive as hell and I have to spend half of my salary to find a good accommodation.

Now, coming to the issue; when I got the offer I did some research and the salary seem just above average to me. The free shuttle service and great campus felt like a great perk hence I decided to join here. There are small villages near to the campus but then its not well connected to the main city and hence my wife has to suffer.

Its been only a month and I still have another offer which seems a better alternative now hence I want to gracefully quit from here as soon as possible. How to politely resign and ask for early exit?

Comment: You should be aware that the potential research organizations are very easily determinable from your information and I don't know how many newcomers they have per month. Also, as far as I know, they offer multiple other perks (like a nearly free gym, private healthcare program for you and your dependents, child care and so on) which might spare you money.

Comment: This question had four reopen votes so I reopened it.  Then I saw a duplicate suggestion and closed it as a dupe.  Since what you're asking is how to exit gracefully (not, say, how to negotiate for more money), I think they're duplicate questions even if specific details vary some.  The goal in both is to leave without burning bridges.  If you disagree with the dupe, please [edit] to explain why this case is different.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the possible alternatives for me?

If you are set on taking the other position, politely turn in your written notice to your current employer **after** accepting the other offer.  Make sure any conditions of employment for your new opportunity are met **before** turning in your notice.

While serving your notice period, do your best to be as helpful as possible.

As a side note this came to mind:  There is an old saying that I am sure you have heard that you need to keep in mind "The grass is not always greener on the other side".

Good luck.

Comment: The second offer I need to accept within 15days should I ask them if they can leave in the required time frame, also I haven't given any responsibilities yet so it should not be a problem.

Comment: @johndoe I would think they would be flexible with your start date.  Get all your questions and pre-requisites addressed before turning in your notice to your current company.

Comment: But I know for sure that they wouldn't wait for one month.

Comment: Well if that is the case, I would say to do the best you can by your current employer and move on.